# In a GatsbyJS application How can I conditionally Navigate to a URL using data from state?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

In a GatsbyJs application I'm trying to navigate to a login page if the user information is not available in the state of a component. I do not need to navigate to the login page if the user information is available in the state

The componenent is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

export default class UserLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      userInfo: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    var objlength = Object.keys(this.state.userInfo).length;
    if(objlength === 0){
      navigate('https://localhost:3000/login'); //express server to login page
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("User information", this.state.userInfo);
    axios.get("https://localhost:3000/users", { withCredentials: true })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({userInfo:response})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>This is user information page</p>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Initially the userInfo state is empty so the length is found to be 0, in that case the app will redirect to login page - `https://localhost:3000/login` and will provide an API with user information - `https://localhost:3000/users`. Once the API is providing the user information the state is updated and length will become valid.

But here the following lines of code called continuously(like inside a loop) even though the state is updated with user information

```
if(objlength === 0){
   navigate('https://localhost:3000/login'); //express server to login page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty generic example of a `Session` component that does what you're looking for, but instead of merely rendering the single page, it provides the session as React Context to be consumed in any descendent component:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
import deepEqual from "deep-equal"
import api from "lib/api"

export const SessionState = React.createContext()
const { Provider, Consumer } = SessionState

export default class Session extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
    isLoading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData()
  }

  updateSession = user => {
    if (!deepEqual(user, this.state.user)) {
      this.setState({ user })
    }

    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }

  handleError = () => {
    this.setState({
      user: null,
      isLoading: false,
    })
  }

  signIn = props =>
    api
      .signIn(props)
      .then(props => this.updateSession(props))
      .catch(error => {
        this.handleError()
      })

  signOut = () =>
    api
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ user: null })
      })
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/dashboard/")
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)

  loadData = () =>
    api
      .user()
      .then(this.updateSession)
      .catch(this.handleError)

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          signIn: this.signIn,
          signOut: this.signOut,
          reload: this.loadData,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export const useSession = () => useContext(SessionState)
```

Instead of duplicating this logic or making additional requests in a descendent component, you can consume the state in a simple function-based component like so:

```
import { useSession } from "./Session"

const Example = () => {
  const { user, isLoading } = useSession()
  
  if (user) {
    // show user content when user present, even if isLoading
    return <div>User content here</div>
  } else {
    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading…</div>
    }

    // no user and not loading
    navigate("/login")
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to debug without seeing a live CodeSandbox. However, one approach that may help you to avoid that call (`objlength === 0`) is setting a helper in your state to check if the API request has ended or not. Initially:

```
this.state = {
  userInfo: {},
  isApiRequestDone: false
}
```

Then, in your promise:

```
.then((response) => {
  this.setState({userInfo:response})
  this.setState({isApiRequestDone:true})
})
```

Finally:

```
if(objlength === 0 && !isApiRequestDone){
   navigate('https://localhost:3000/login'); //express server to login page
}
```

This is an initial workaround but for now, it may help you to bypass the redirection.